# Windows 7 power schemes selection in system tray - number of options

Tags: windows-7, power-management, notification-area

When I click the battery symbol in Winodws 7 tray, it offers only the last to used power schemes. To use a different one, you have to clik again to open some window, where you can select from more...

Is there a way to display more (preferably all) available power schemes?

Comment: Thanks for answers. I hoped it will be possible by some simple registry change, without installing any new apps.

Comment: Well, you could make batch files and apply shortcuts to them. In the batch files, run powercfg with the desired switches to modify the power scheme. That way, no additional software is installed.

Answer (score 1):

**[Power Plan Assistant](http://www.powerplan7.com/)** can be used with any 32-bit or 64-bit edition of Windows® 7. It allows a user to switch between the built-in and custom power plans (all the plans, not just 2 of them, as it is when operating via system Power icon), auto-switch a PC to 'High Performance' on plugging in and much more ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may like this free and open source tool, [SchemeHK](http://code.google.com/p/michtatools/).

You can easily choose from all plans from the tray:

[image]

and assign hotkeys to switch power levels:

[image]

You could also use [Autohotkey](http://autohotkey.com) to make custom keyboard shortcuts that launch [powercfg](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28WS.10%29.aspx) in the background with certain switches. That way you can also change your power settings via the keyboard.